# Travis unattended install with no first-run prompts (completions)

Tags: autocomplete, installation, travis-ci, unattended-processing

I want to install [TravisCI CLI](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb) unattended.

With a ruby 2.1 runtime, as recommended by linked readme, the travis cli base tools can be installed with `gem`:

```
gem install travis -v 1.8.0 --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

However, upon first run travis will prompt the user to install completions.

I desire no first-run behavior of deployed installed software.

My case may be simplified by having only one target user: `ubuntu`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically for travis 1.8.0, since that version is locked in your gem install example; the [`install_completions`](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb/blob/v1.8.0/lib/travis/tools/completion.rb#L21) method can be called directly:

```
# This step operates on the current users ~/.travis data,
# as the target user eg: "$su ubuntu"

ruby \
  -r /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/travis-1.8.0/lib/travis/tools/completion.rb \
  -e "Travis::Tools::Completion.install_completion"
```

The `/var/lib/gems/2.1.0` prefix can be determined with `gem env`; `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` key.

I browsed the 'gems' subfolder to locate the Travis files specifically.

*Note: If there a multiple users, the generated `~/.travis` directory should be safe to copy to other users.*

---

Alternatively, if you want the prompt silenced/squelched without completions, there is a simple .yaml file: `~/.travis/config.yml` to which the follow keys can be added:

```
---
checked_completion: true
completion_version: 1.8.0
```